# Problems with achartengine

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I am trying to build a char using the library from achartengine (http://www.achartengine.org/). So i try to run SalesGrowthChart.java on my own aplication so when someone clicks on a button it will show him the chart .

This is my code :

```
private IChart[] mCharts = new IChart[]{new generatedchart()};
```

And i try to generate it like this

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), generatedchart.class);
                 myIntent=mCharts[0].execute(this);
            }
        });
```

But this won't work. How can i make it to work.Hope you understand what i am saying.
This is the error :

> The method execute(Context) in the type IChart is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){})

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the "this" mentioned inside that method refers to a view (which is what you are creating at that point.)

The method execute needs a Context, so you need to get the context in a different manner.

You should try getting the context like this:

```
YourActivityName.this
```

Which in your code would be like:

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), generatedchart.class);
                 myIntent=mCharts[0].execute(YourActivityName.this);
            }
        });
```

Comment: How can i do this? I am new to java and android.

Comment: I just posted how to do it and how it will look like in your example. You just need to replace "YourActivityName" with the the Class name that you have extending Activity. That is, the name of the class (and .java file) where you have this code on.

Comment: now when i click on the button , nothing happens. That is very strange.

Comment: forgot the startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `this` within `execute()`, it is referring to the `OnClickListener` class because of the dynamic class declaration.  Try using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`.

Comment: I think getApplicationContext() will only work if his activity(s) are declared within an application and he has one equally defined in manifest file.